# Array search with ransack through a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have a table called `key_words` which has one column called `name`.

Then I have another table called `publications` with a column called `key_words` which is of `array` type.

When I create a publication the value saved in `key_words` is something like this `["1", "29", "40"]` (these are ids saved in `key_words` table)

How can I find a publication if I type for example `computers` in a searchable `input`?

In this moment I have a `search_form_for` to find by the publication `title` and `description`.

```
= search_form_for @search, url: publications_path do |f|
  #custom-search-input
    .input-group.col-md-12
      = f.input :title_or_short_description_or_description_cont, input_html: { class: 'form-control input-sm' }, placeholder: 'Buscar', label: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a third table `key_words_publications` to store the relationship instead of the array column. Check out the docs for HABTM [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

```
class Publication
  has_and_belongs_to_many :key_words
end

class KeyWord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :publications
end
```

Then you should be able to do something like:
`key_words_name_cont`